# Send an Email notification to the admin for pending order status in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

In WooCommerce, when a customer goes to checkout from cart and submit the order, if the payment is not processed, the order is set to "pending" payment. The Admin doesn't received any email about.

I would like to send an email to Admin for this kind of orders. How can I do it?

Comment: woocommerce has A LOT of hooks, I'm sure one of them might be helpful: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Answer (score 23):

**UPDATE 2** *(Change from `woocommerce_new_order` to `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` thanks to Céline Garel)*

This code will be fired in all possible cases when a new order **get a pending status** and will trigger automatically a "New Order" email notification:

```
// New order notification only for "Pending" Order status
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'pending_new_order_notification', 20, 1 );
function pending_new_order_notification( $order_id ) {

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Only for "pending" order status
    if( ! $order->has_status( 'pending' ) ) return;

    // Send "New Email" notification (to admin)
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

---

A more customizable version of the code (if needed), that will make **pending Orders more visible**:

```
// New order notification only for "Pending" Order status
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'pending_new_order_notification', 20, 1 );
function pending_new_order_notification( $order_id ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Only for "pending" order status
    if( ! $order->has_status( 'pending' ) ) return;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Email_New_Order object
    $wc_email = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order'];

    ## -- Customizing Heading, subject (and optionally add recipients)  -- ##
    // Change Subject
    $wc_email->settings['subject'] = __('{site_title} - New customer Pending order ({order_number}) - {order_date}');

    // Change Heading
    $wc_email->settings['heading'] = __('New customer Pending Order'); 
    // $wc_email->settings['recipient'] .= ',name@email.com'; // Add email recipients (coma separated)

    // Send "New Email" notification (to admin)
    $wc_email->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This version Allow to customize the email heading, subject, add recipients...

Comment: dear this function looks very awesome but its not working for me.i am using wp 4.8 version.

Comment: @burhanjamil **I have updated my answer**, please try it. I have changed the hook and now it should work in any cases for "pending orders status"… Now the code is more effective, compact and lighter. There is 2 versions one that just send the default "new order" notification and the other one that will allow some customizations (if needed)…

Comment: Its not working. I have also test by creating simple.txt file either the hook is calling or not. Its call the function but can't trigger the order email.

Comment: Thank you works straight out of the box. Wordpress version 5.2.2

Comment: Works great. Thank you. I just have one question? I would like to send email when order is pending and payment method is credit card. How could I do that?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec , does this code trigger once? once a day?

Answer (score 3):

I've tried with **LoicTheAztec answer**, @LoicTheAztec thanks a lot for your great code.

I have just changed the action hook from `woocommerce_new_order` to `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` to get it to work.

Here is the action : `add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'pending_new_order_notification', 20, 1 );`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this fix! when I used `woocommerce_new_order` the order mail arrived without the products, but using `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` fixed it, and the mail arrive as it sould :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks @LoicTheAztec** – Here is a version of your code that sends the email after 10 minutes of the status being "Pending Payment".

It's utilising action scheduler and avoids the admin receiving pending emails when an order is only temporarily in that state such as for an external card payment.

Note the filter `woocommerce_new_order_email_allows_resend` which allows the new order email to be sent more than once.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_order_email_allows_resend', '__return_true' );

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'pending_new_order_notification', 20, 1 );

function pending_new_order_notification( $order_id ) {
    $delayTime = 600;

    as_schedule_single_action(time() + $delayTime, 'queue_pending_email', array( $order_id ), 'customActions');
}

add_action( 'queue_pending_email', function( $order_id ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Only for "pending" order status
    if( ! $order->has_status( 'pending' ) ) return;
    
    // Get an instance of the WC_Email_New_Order object
    $wc_email = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order'];

    ## -- Customizing Heading, subject (and optionally add recipients)  -- ##
    // Change Subject
    $wc_email->settings['subject'] = __('{site_title} - New customer pending order ({order_number}) - {order_date}');

    // Change Heading
    $wc_email->settings['heading'] = __('New Order Still Pending'); 
    // $wc_email->settings['recipient'] .= ',name@email.com'; // Add email recipients (coma separated)

    $wc_email->settings['additional_content'] = __('This order is currently pending.');

    // Send "New Email" notification (to admin)
    $wc_email->trigger( $order_id );
}, 20, 1 );
```