# How to send Customer invoice / Order details email notification Automatically In Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I want to send  Customer invoice / Order details email notification Automatically In Woocommerce.When i checking  Customer invoice / Order email notification in woocommerce it have only way to send  Customer invoice / Order email manually.I want to send  Customer invoice / Order email notification when order status is pending payment.If there any function is available send  Customer invoice / Order email automatically.Could You Please Help Me.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: This answer will help you get started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375143/send-an-email-notification-to-the-admin-for-pending-order-status-in-woocommerce

Answer (score -2):

Use the woocommerce_email_headers filter with a condition that matches the Customer invoice / Order details email.

Make sure you set the email addresses like `<your@email.com>` as `your@email.com` alone failed for me.

```
function add_bcc_to_certain_emails( $headers, $object ) {

    $bcc_emails = '<your@email.com>, <another@email.com>';      

    // email types/objects to add bcc to
    $add_bcc_to = array(
        'customer_invoice',//for the manually triggered Customer invoice / Order details email
    );

    // if our email object is in our array
    if ( in_array( $object, $add_bcc_to ) ) {
        // change our headers
        $headers = array( 
            $headers,
            'Bcc: '.$bcc_emails.'\r\n',
            );
    }

    return $headers;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_bcc_to_certain_emails', 10, 2 );
```

Snippet amended from https://jessepearson.net/2016/10/adding-bcc-emails-woocommerce/