# Delay email for woocommerce custom function for 20 minutes

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using *"[Send an Email notification to the admin for pending order status in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375143/send-an-email-notification-to-the-admin-for-pending-order-status-in-woocommerce/45382112#45382112)"* answer code to send a customized email notification on pending order status.

How can I delay this email notifications send by the function for 20 minutes?

So the email should be sent after the delay of 20 minutes.

I have tried tried to put the sleep function but it is not convenient.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When using some code picked on StackOverFlow, always add the link in your question. If you don't make real changes to the code, the link is just enough.

Comment: yeah, next time I will take care of that. can you please help me out with this. you wrote this piece of code can you please help me out to put a delay of 20 minutes?