# Email notification to the admin and customer for pending order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am trying to make Email notification that goes to the admin and also to customer for a pending order.

I am using *"[Send an Email notification to the admin for pending order status in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375143/send-an-email-notification-to-the-admin-for-pending-order-status-in-woocommerce/45382112#45382112)"* answer code, that sends the email only to the admin and I want to sent it also to the customer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some feed back on my answer will be appreciated please in the comment zone below the answer Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add also an email notification to customer as "On Hold" for example, like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'pending_new_order_notification', 20, 1 );
function pending_new_order_notification( $order_id ) {

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Only for "pending" order status
    if( ! $order->has_status( 'pending' ) ) return;

    // Send "New Email" notification (to admin)
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order_id );

    // Send "On Hold Email" notification (to customer)
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Since WooCommerce 5+:** [Allow re-sending New Order Notification in WooCommerce 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604256/allow-re-sending-new-order-notification-in-woocommerce-5/66604522#66604522)