# Disable email sent to admin when a order is processing

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm using [Send an Email notification to the admin for pending order status in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375143/send-an-email-notification-to-the-admin-for-pending-order-status-in-woocommerce/45382112#45382112) which works fine.

Is there a way I can disable admin email when the order is change to pending>processing ? because when ever I change to pending > processing " new order " email generates and duplicates mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `woocommerce_email` action hook and inside that callback function you can remove `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification` this action hook. check below code. Code goes in active theme functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'stop_processing_email_admin' );
function stop_processing_email_admin( $email_class ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
}
```

Comment: I know this works for cash on delivery, is it possible to get the same process for credit card purchases @Bhautik

Comment: Yes, it will work with both process.

Comment: Hey @Bhautik when a customer places an order via credit card it auto changes from pending to processing, is there a specific hook so i can keep it on pending when new order is placed. so far COD works fine new order goes as pending but credit card it auto changed pending to processing.